# Установить игру на Linux

Tags: linux

Как скачать с интернета игру на компьютер с системой Linux?
 Расскажите в подробностях.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, последний вопрос там обновлён аж 5 октября 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Windows: игры запускаются в wine (не все).

Linux: игры ставятся из репозиториев (какой у Вас дистрибутив). А еще можно [так](http://ualinux.com/lgp)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сказал так: существует 2 пути, как поиграть на `Linux` в игры:

**Путь первый:** установка игры с репозитория. Как это сделать: 1. Установить пакет [этот](http://archive.ualinux.com/ubuntu/main/all/ualinux-repository_0.1_all.deb) и автоматически добавится репозиторий. Потом из менеджера пакетов ставить игры из добавленного репозитория. 2.  Добавить вручную:

```
Ubuntu 10.04:   deb http://archive.ualinux.com/ubuntu lucid mainUbuntu 10.10:   deb http://archive.ualinux.com/ubuntu maverick mainUbuntu 11.04 :  deb http://archive.ualinux.com/ubuntu natty mainUbuntu 11.10:   deb http://archive.ualinux.com/ubuntu oneiric mainUbuntu 12.04:   deb http://archive.ualinux.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Все зависит, опять же, от дистрибутива, который у Вас стоит. Если у Вас `Ubuntu` (а это на 90% так), то воспользуйтесь 1 или 2-м шагом. Первый удобнее.

**Путь второй:** Установить `wine` и скачивать и запускать игры, предназначенные для `Windows OS`. Как установить `wine` описано [тут](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/wine). Или просто выполнить в консоле

`sudo apt-get install wine`

Comment: А если не убунту? Как быть с путем первым? А если вдруг zypper вместо apt-get, то тогда путь второй то же зашел в тупик?

Comment: ну я ориентировался по популярности дистрибутива (http://distrowatch.com) Если не deb архитектура то тут уже другой случай.

Answer (score 0):

> Цитата
>
> как скачать с интернета игру на компьютер

---

Cтавишь браузер и скачиваешь. Ну или поискать в [Google](www.google.com) на наличие download-менеджеров интересных/нужных. Но это, опять же, если идти по линии задаваемого вопросса. Если играть - либо Windows в `DualBoot`, либо - через `Wine`.